# Multi-level Accordion Menu Improvements?

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I am looking to build a multi-level accordion menu.
I have built this menu ( http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogdovx ) so far but i am new to jquery and reaching the limit of my knowledge with it.

How can this be improved on?
I need it to only drop down items that have a sub UL's and collapse siblings/children on open.

Any help in improving my code would be appreciated.
Cheers!

Code from codepen:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".main > li > a").click(function() {
      $('.main ul').slideUp();
      if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
      }
   })

   $(".main > li > ul > li > a").click(function() {
      $('.main ul ul').slideUp();
      if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
      }
   })

   $(".main ul ul li > a").click(function() {
      $('.main ul ul ul').slideUp();
      if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
      }
   })
  
});
```

```css
ul.children {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main">
  <li class="page_has_children">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_has_children">
        <a href="#">Sub Link</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Sub Link</a>
            <ul class="children">
              <li><a href="#">Child Link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="page_has_children">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_has_children">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_has_children">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_has_children">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to improve this is to create some handles so that you don't have to duplicate your code so much. The simplest way is to just put a class on any parent links. By doing this, you only need call to add event handlers.

```js
$(".parent-link").click(function() {
  var children = $(this).next(); //shorthand for the next ul
  var parents = $(this).parents(".children"); //any uls above me

  //close all other uls not above me in the tree
  $('.children').not(parents).slideUp();
  
  //open this if its closed
  children.filter(":hidden").slideDown();
})
```

```css
ul.children {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main">
  <li class=".parent-link">
    <a class="parent-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_has_children">
        <a class="parent-link" href="#">Sub Link</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li>
            <a class="parent-link" href="#">Sub Sub Link</a>
            <ul class="children">
              <li><a href="#">Child Link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="page_has_children">
        <a class="parent-link" href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_has_children">
    <a class="parent-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_has_children">
    <a class="parent-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_has_children">
    <a class="parent-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry i should have added i will be using wordpress for this and will be limited to the classes that wp-list-pages / wp-nav-menu uses which are similar to the classes i have setup in my code above.

Unless i add the classes via jquery.